# ArcMap basemap not dynamically responding to editing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, basemap, dynamic

I am having an issue with editing on a basemap. For instance, while my editor is active and I am dropping points (tree shapes) on the basemap, I cannot see them until I move the map with a pan a bit. Only then are my shapes visible. In the case of polygons, I cannot see the shape while clicking, but when I move the map with a pan, the polygon appears on the map. Even when I zoom in and out, I can zoom in, but nothing happens until I move the map with a pan and then I see the action of zooming in.

What could be the problem here?
ArcMap version: 10.8.2

Comment: Update your graphic card drivers?

Comment: Did, still have the same issue.